# Edit vim syntax highlighting options for a specific file type

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, markdown

When I edit a .markdown file in vim, the highlighting looks like this:

[image]

I am using a light colour scheme and the builtin vim `.markdown` settings (no plugins - I found them to be worse). The problem is it is interpreting anything between `_`...`_` as italic text, and for some reason inverting the colours to white on black. Obviously even for the parts that aren't latex I don't want the inverse colours.

How can I turn off the inverse-colour highlighting for things between `_`...`_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:syn list` shows you all syntax definitions; the group for `_this_` is `markdownItalic`. To change the visual appearance, just link this syntax group to a different highlight group (`:hi` lists them all), e.g. to turn off the highlighting:

```
hi link markdownItalic Normal
```

You can put that into your `~/.vimrc` to make it permanent. You may want to consider switching to a high-color terminal (if possible); it looks like you're running with very few (2 / 16) colors.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I am using a high colour terminal, but unfortunately it doesn't render italics :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have Tex fragments inside your Markdown document. An alternative approach would highlight those with the correct syntax. My [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) allows to highlight just those regions as Tex, e.g.:

```
:11,42SyntaxRange tex
```

Comment: Hmm, I would need some way of detecting the ranges automatically based on $, $$, \\[ etc. Sounds like a good project at some stage.

Comment: The plugin also has an API that lets you specify start and end patterns for the (Tex) range. The command from the answer is mostly for manual definition of a range.